# Web API starting process

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I believe I am having permissions problems running a Selenium PhantomJS driver from a web API service. I have tried impersonating the service through various admin accounts, but I still encounter the same error. How do I determine what configuration file is throwing the error?  I am receiving this error by printing process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to  initialize
  ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access is denied.
  ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Access is denied.
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.SafeImpersonate(SafeTokenHandle userToken, WindowsIdentity wi, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.SafeRevertToSelf(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.Impersonate()
```

Comment: Well what code are you using currently? What version of Web API? Reproducible on another machine? What version of PhantomJS? What version of Selenium? What Windows OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very strange because Web Driver don't requires you to dynamically alter the configuration file. I suppose you are trying to do everything by yourself : do not reinvent the wheel because all this stuff is already done by Selenium Support Classes.

In order to pilot WebDriver in Web Api :

- Create/Add a Web Api Project
- Add a reference to the Nuget package [Selenium WebDriver Support Classes](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.Support/)
- Add the Web Driver code to your actions

A very basic way to get the title of https://stackoverflow.com/ could be :

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS;
...
public string Get()
{
    // c:\phantomjs contains phantomjs.exe
    // if blank, Web Driver will download the latest version
    IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(@"c:\phantomjs");
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
    string title = driver.Title;
    driver.Quit();
    return title;
}
```

- That's all !

Depending on your hosting, support Classes can have some problems when trying to start phantomjs by itself ; simply change the application pool identity to a power user.

Comment: looks about right I will test :)>  I had to revert to remote selenium to get a headless driver without exe.